# Django PWA serviceworker.js code is showing on home page

Tags: django, nginx, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

When I go to home page of my website, I'm met with code of my `serviceworker.js` which looks like this:

```js
var staticCacheName = 'djangopwa-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/base_layout'
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (requestUrl.origin === location.origin) {
      if ((requestUrl.pathname === '/')) {
        event.respondWith(caches.match('/base_layout'));
        return;
      }
    }
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
});
```

This is a code from [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-pwa-of-a-django-project/).

After every "hard refresh" (CTRL + F5 or CTRL + R) it shows my regular home page and the link doesn't change at all.

I do think it's something to do with nginx configuration but I'm not sure what is wrong.

settings.py

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PWA_SERVICE_WORKER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/scripts', 'serviceworker.js')

...

PWA_APP_NAME = 'Timetable Ease'
PWA_APP_DESCRIPTION = "Timetable Ease PWA"
PWA_APP_THEME_COLOR = '#3D36FF'
PWA_APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#aaaadd'
PWA_APP_DISPLAY = 'standalone'
PWA_APP_SCOPE = '/'
PWA_APP_ORIENTATION = 'any'
PWA_APP_START_URL = '/'
PWA_APP_STATUS_BAR_COLOR = 'default'
PWA_APP_ICONS = [
    {
        'src': 'static/images/logo.png',
        'sizes': '160x160'
    }
]
PWA_APP_ICONS_APPLE = [
    {
        'src': 'static/images/logo.png',
        'sizes': '160x160'
    }
]
PWA_APP_SPLASH_SCREEN = [
    {
        'src': 'static/images/logo.png',
        'media': '(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)'
    }
]
PWA_APP_DIR = 'ltr'
PWA_APP_LANG = 'en-US'
PWA_APP_DEBUG_MODE = False
```

project urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls')),
    path('', include('pwa.urls')),
]
```

app urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home.home, name='home'),
]
```

home.py

```py
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

layout_base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static tags %}
<html lang="hr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% load pwa %}
    {% progressive_web_app_meta %}

...
```

nginx configuration

```
server_tokens               off;
access_log                  /var/log/nginx/timetableease.access.log;
error_log                   /var/log/nginx/timetableease.error.log;

server {
  server_name               .timetableease.com;
  listen                    80;
  return                    307 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/ubuntu/timetableease/static/;
    expires off;
  }

  location /service-worker.js {
    alias /home/ubuntu/timetableease/static/scripts/serviceworker.js;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/server.key;
}
```

Comment: Post the full template, please.  It might be an issue with how you are doing step 6 of the tutorial.

Comment: @raphael here...